# How to call a OSGI servlet through AJAX from a normal JAVA class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, osgi, aem

This sounds weird,but I have a project requirment where I have a OSGI bundle that have servlet and I need to call this servlet in another web project in java.

**Requirement :** When I hit the AJAX request (my servlet inside OSGI bundle is registered on path - `"bin/redeem/search"`) to my OSGI bundle consisting the servlet,then it should return the response.

**What I did :** I created a OSGI bundle that have a servlet with business logic.

**Development setup :** I am using MyEclipse as an IDE and I setup a web project that is suppose to fire the AJAX request to the OSGI bundle.

**or, Is there a way I can package my servlet either JAR or WAR and later I can fire a AJAX request from other web app ?**

suggestion will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have some CQ5 instance with some servlet which is bind to url `http://somedomain/bin/redeem/search`. 
And you need to call it from other regular web project.

Then you can use Apache HttpClient to make a call to your servlet.

It can look like:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://somedomain/bin/redeem/search");

try {
  int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

  //check status code

  byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

  // Do something with response from your serlvet

} catch (Exception e) {

    // handle exception
} finally {
  method.releaseConnection();
}
```

Also, probably, first, you will need to login to system or allow anonymous access.
Full example you can find [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html).

If I understood you wrong, please provide details or some pseudo-code.